# Galería web automatizada

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

estoy en un dilema, mi cliente quiere que en una carpeta del hosting se coloquen imágenes y que en una galería se muestren de manera automática.
Estoy iniciando en web, la verdad no sé por donde empezar para lograr ese requerimiento, si alguien me puede orientar por favor! =/

Comment: Puedes utilizar cualquiera de estos recursos, para empezar, claro: [Carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/) o [Thumbnail Gallery](https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-thumbnail-gallery). Saludos

Comment: Hola Oz, para que te puedan ayudar tendrias que tener algo armado y pasar estructura de la base de datos, y la parte html de la galeria mas el php, busca en google galeria php mysql y salen muchos ejemplos, podes hacerlo de dos formas una es armando un form para subir fotos que guarden en la base el nombre y la direccion y dsp desde tu php obtener los datos y mostrarlos en un for, o subir fotos a una carpeta directamente y dsp con php entrar a la carpeta, contar cuantas fotos hay y hacer un for y mostrarlas, ese seria un ejemplo sin base de datos, asi que como te digo, busca un poco ejemplos

Comment: @juan vaya parece que ese última alternativa funcionaría, solo que estoy trabajando bajo una plantilla que ya cuenta con galería y quieren respetar ese formato, crees sea factible cargar directamente con un for a la galería que ya tiene la plantilla?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como te dije en el ejemplo esta seria la forma de hacerlo sin usar base de datos, ahora amoldalo a tu plantilla.
Lo que necesitas para que esto funcione es que las imagenes esten renombradas del 1 en adelante.

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>Document</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <?php
                $pCarpeta="images/";
                $mascaraTotal="*.jpg,*.JPG,*.png,*.PNG, *.JPEG, *.jpeg";
                $total=count(glob($pCarpeta . "/{" . $mascaraTotal . "}",GLOB_BRACE));
                $contador = 1;
                while ( $contador<= $total) {
                    echo "<img src='".$pCarpeta.''.$contador.".jpg' 
                    style='width: 400px; height: 300px;'/>";
                    $contador++;
                }
        ?> 
        </body>
        </html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias por tu apoyo!